# PostgreSQL 9.3 debugger using OS X

Tags: postgresql, debugging, pgadmin, postgresql-9.3

Using OS X & PostgreSQL 9.3, how do I enable the built in PL/SQL debugger & add the menu option for debugging functions in PG Admin?

I had no problems using Windows 8 & 7, but no luck with OS X.

I already tried adding the following entry to postgresql.conf-

```
shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/postgresql/plugin_debugger'
```

also tried various of combinations of that with (with/out .so, /postgresql etc.)

and executed this query:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pldbgapi;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, The problem was that SQL functions cannot be debugged in PostgreSQL, only PLSQL, which is why the menu option was not shown. (To be able to debug, create your function using PLSQL as the selected language).

For future reference, this the correct entry in `postgresql.conf`:

```
shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger'
```